# Preventing repeating value in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Making a game and am trying to get each crystal to pull a random number from a Math.floor(Math.random()). But the goal is to have each crystal be a different number. I tried making if statements and saying that one crystal cannot equal another, but do not seem to be having luck with those methods. Do I need to make all the crystals their own functions?

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
        //Varriable for the number you have to guess
        var targetNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 101) +19;
    
      //Varriable that edits the DOM for the number we have to guess
      $(".guess_this_number").text(targetNumber);
    
      //Our number that starts at zero
      var counter = 0;
    
      //"Your Number" is chaning the DOM of to equal whatever is added
      $(".userTotal").text(counter);
    
      //Wins that starts at zero 
      var wins = 0;
      //Update DOM with wins
      $("#wins").text(wins);
    
      //losseses that starts at zero 
      var losses = 0;
      //Update DOM with losses
      $("#losses").text(losses);
    
      //The computer generated number is determined by a math random
      var targetNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 101) +19;
      $('.guess_this_number').text(targetNumber);
    
    
          // Object array of all the crystals. Maps a random number to each crystal
          var numbers = {
            "crystal_1": Math.floor(Math.random() * 11) +1,
            "crystal_2": Math.floor(Math.random() * 11) +1,
            "crystal_3": Math.floor(Math.random() * 11) +1,
            "crystal_4": Math.floor(Math.random() * 11) +1,
          };
          console.log(numbers)
          
          //For each 
          // key is the crystal and the value is the math.floor 
          $.each(numbers, function(key, value){
           $('.'+key).click(function(){
    
            //Counter will increase from the value of each number
            counter += value;
    
            //Prevents same number appearing twice...maybe??? 
            // if ((numbers["crystal_1"]) === (numbers["crystal_2"]) || 
            //     (numbers["crystal_1"]) === (numbers["crystal_3"]) ||
            //     (numbers["crystal_1"]) === (numbers["crystal_4"]) ||
            //     (numbers["crystal_2"]) === (numbers["crystal_3"]) ||
            //     (numbers["crystal_2"]) === (numbers["crystal_4"]) ||
            //     (numbers["crystal_3"]) === (numbers["crystal_4"])) {
            // }; nope no luck

            // or...? 
            if ((numbers["crystal_1"]) === (numbers["crystal_2"])) {
              (numbers["crystal_2"]) = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11) +1;
              (numbers["crystal_1"]) != (numbers["crystal_2"]);
            }; //no luck here either


    
            //Counter class is updated with new number, 
            //if go over the goal number lose, add loss, and reset
            $('.userTotal').html(counter);
            if(counter > targetNumber){
             $('#wlMessage').text("You Lose :(" );
               losses ++;
               $('#losses').text(losses);
               counter = 0;
               $(".userTotal").text(counter);
               $(".guess_this_number").text(Math.floor(Math.random() * 101) +19);
             }
    
              //Counter class is updated with new number, 
              //if user number equals goal numer its a win, add win, and reset
             if(counter === targetNumber){
               $('#wlMessage').text("You Won!!!");
               wins ++;
               $('#wins').text(wins);
               counter = 0;
               $(".userTotal").text(counter);
               $(".guess_this_number").text(Math.floor(Math.random() * 101) +19);
             }
    
           });
    
         });
    
        });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML> 
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
 
 <title>Crystal Game</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/reset.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Smlep5jCw/wG7hdkwQ/Z5nLIefveQRIY9nfy6xoR1uRYBtpZgI6339F5dgvm/e9B"
        crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/style.css">
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



</head>

<body>
 <!-- Container --> 
 <div class="container">
  
  <!-- Title --> 
  <div class="jumbotron">
   <h1 class="text-center">Crystal Game</h1>
   <div class="text-center">
    
    <!-- Instructions --> 
    <div class ="row">
     <div class="col-12">
      <h5>Instructions</h5>
      <p> lorem ipsum some instructions</p>
     </div>
    </div>

    <!-- The Random Computer Number --> 
    <div class ="row">
     <div class="col-12">
      <div class="col-12">Match the number</div>
      <div class ="guess_this_number"></div>
     </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Crystals --> 
    <div class ="row">
       <div class ="col-3 crystal_1"><img src="assets/images/crystal-01.svg"></div>
       <div class ="col-3 crystal_2"><img src="assets/images/crystal-02.svg"></div>
       <div class ="col-3 crystal_3"><img src="assets/images/crystal-03.svg"></div>
       <div class ="col-3 crystal_4"><img src="assets/images/crystal-04.svg"></div>
    </div>

    <!-- User number --> 
    <div class ="row">
     <div class="col-12">
      <div class="col-12">Your number</div>
      <div class ="userTotal"></div>
     </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Score --> 
    <div class ="row">
     <div class="col-12">
      <hr>
<!--       <div class="col-12">Score</div>
 -->      <div id="wlMessage"></div>
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-6">
        <div><h6>Wins:</h6></div>
        <div id ="wins"></div>
       </div>
       <div class="col-6">
        <div><h6>Losses:</h6></div>
        <div id ="losses"></div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>


 </div>

<script src="assets/javascript/game.js"></script>

</body>
```

Comment: Have you considered declaring an array and adding each crystal's number to the arrayl prior to releasing a new number make sure the number doesn't exist in the array group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my comment I asked if you considered using an array to hold an inventory of numbers before releasing it for use; I wrote you up a quick example I hope will help or lead you in the right direction.

The below example creates an inventory array for numbers generated by clicking the button, every click adds the number to the array and before doing a certain function the number is validated against the array to display if it has been generated before.

Essentially this code is pretty much to identify unique numbers when generating them. I've done my best to comment each step to make it easy to understand;

Please see the code below:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Smlep5jCw/wG7hdkwQ/Z5nLIefveQRIY9nfy6xoR1uRYBtpZgI6339F5dgvm/e9B" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" />
      <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700,400italic|Roboto+Mono:400,500|Material+Icons" />-->

      <title>Ilan's Test</title>
   </head>
   <body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-sm-12' style="margin-top:10px;">
            <div class="form-group">
                <a class="btn btn-primary" id="clickme" style="color:#FFFFFF;">Generate Number</a>
            </div>
            <div id="results">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-o+RDsa0aLu++PJvFqy8fFScvbHFLtbvScb8AjopnFD+iEQ7wo/CG0xlczd+2O/em" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
      <!--<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>-->

<script type="text/javascript">
    // Declare our global variables
    var numcheck = new Array(); // this array will hold all generated numbers
    var newnum; // this is our new number placeholder
    var exists; // this is our boolean indicator

    // On button click we run this function
    $('#clickme').click(function(){
            // Assign a new random number to our variable
            newnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11) + 1;
            // Itirate through our numcheck array and check if the number exists         
            $.each(numcheck, function(i, item) {

                if (item == newnum){
                    // If the number exists, set our indicator to true, exit this loop
                    exists = true;
                    return false;
                } else {
                    // If the number does not exist, set our indicator to true
                    exists = false;
                }
            });

            // Check our indicator what happened when we went through the array, the reason I use indicator is because if I have additional code I need this value in I can use it later
            if (exists == true){
                // If the number exists, indicate in my results log the number has been used
                $('#results').append('<span class="text-danger">' + newnum + ' has already been used.</span><br>');
            } else {
                // If the number does not exist in our array, indicate in the results it's a fresh number and do any custom coding needed in the below clause
                $('#results').append('<span class="text-success">New number generated: ' + newnum + '</span><br>');
            }

            // Add the number to the array regardless if true or false so we can analzye its length in the future if needed, the array is our number inventory which tells us when a number has been previously used
            numcheck.push(newnum);

    });

</script>

   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I will take a look and give it a go.